# Sql like query that ignore the first word completely

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want the sql like query that ignores the first word from the field completely, I want remaining word.

For example:
Name: 
John Smith 
ABC XYZ PQR

Output : 
Smith 
XYZ PQR

I want the string after the first (whitespace)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want a "LIKE" query ? or the result not to display the first word...

Comment: I want to do it with LIKE query

Comment: you can retrieve the result and remove the first word.

Comment: so if you do "LIKE %B%", you don't want it to return "XYZ PQR" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT RIGHT(Name, LENGTH(Name) - LOCATE(' ', Name))
FROM mytable
```

Function [**`LOCATE`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) returns the position of the *first* occurrence of space inside the column (if any). Using [**`RIGHT`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_right) we can easily extract the part that comes *right after* this space occurrence.

Comment: thanks its work fine, Can you please explain whats happen LENGTH(Name) - doing

Answer (score 4):

Just use it.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(name, LOCATE(' ', name)+1) FROM mytable
```

*name = Field Name,

*mytable= Table Name

Comment: Works like charm !